# WebCore crashing in NSOperationQueue operation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I can't seem what is wrong with my code. Here's some code in my AHInstagramImageData

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

for (NSDictionary * comment in imgCmt){
        AHInstagramImageComment * instagramImgComment  = [[AHInstagramImageComment alloc] initWithData:comment];
        [comments insertObject:instagramImgComment atIndex:0];
        [instagramImgComment release];
    }
}

and then on the AHInstagramImageComment I have:

-(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self calculateCommentsHeight];

    return self;
}

- (void) calculateCommentsHeight
{
    NSString *combinedComment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.username, self.text];
    CGFloat desiredHeight = [combinedComment sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kCommentsMaxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip].height;

    if (desiredHeight >= 50){
        commentHeight_ = desiredHeight;
    } else {
        commentHeight_ = 50;
    }

    commentHeight_ += kTimestampMaxHeight;
    commentHeight_ += 5;
}
```

So essentialy I had initializing the AHInstagramImageData in a background queue:

```
 [weakSelf.backgroundQueue_ addOperationWithBlock:^{
                             NSArray *arr = [response valueForKey:@"data"];
                             int startingIndex = [[AHImageDataSource sharedDataSource] count];
                             for (NSDictionary * data in arr){
                                 AHInstagramImageData * imgData = [[AHInstagramImageData alloc] initWithData:data];
```

}
    }];

Is any of these wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem similiar to this before. There is currently a bug which prevents `[NSString sizeWithFont:]` and `[NSString drawInRect:]` to run on background threads, or via `NSOperations`.

See this link:
[Bug in UIKit string drawing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589768/bug-in-uikit-string-drawing-method)

You have a few options:

1. Don't use `sizeWithFont:` with `NSOperations`.
2. Set max operation count on your `NSOperationQueue` to 1:

   `[queue setMaxConcurrentOperations:1];`
3. Use Core Text and `NSAttributedStrings`, which have their own "`sizeWithFont`" method: `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`
4. Use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue];` to run operations on the main thread.

Comment: hmm..doing so in the main thread will block the UI right, if I were doing this in a for loop of 1000 iterations, it owuld be pretty horrible

Comment: @adit you can do it on a background thread, but make sure to set the maxConcurrentOperations on your queue to 1.

Answer (score 4):

Core Text is somewhat threadsafe, as described here: [Alternative for sizeWithFont: method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371402/alternative-for-sizewithfont-method)

Using CoreText, I wrote a NSString category which wraps [CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints) and is thread safe. Could be of use to someone finding this post and wanting a different solution. This one is compatible with both iOS 5 and iOS 6, but gives better results on iOS 6 for some reason.

It returns a suggested CGSize for you, but also tells you how many characters it was able to fit at what font size, and takes a constraint.

NSString+SizeCalculation.h

```
@interface NSString (SizeCalculation)

// Uses CoreText instead of UIStringDrawing, since UIStringDrawing is not thread safe
- (CGSize) sizeWithFontName:(NSString*)fontName constraints:(CGSize)constraint targetSize:(CGFloat)target minimumSize:(CGFloat)minimum optimalFontSize:(CGFloat*)optimal fitRange:(NSRange*)range;

@end
```

NSString+SizeCalculation.m

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
@implementation NSString (SizeCalculation)

- (CGSize) sizeWithFontName:(NSString*)fontName constraints:(CGSize)constraint targetSize:(CGFloat)target minimumSize:(CGFloat)minimum optimalFontSize:(CGFloat*)optimal fitRange:(NSRange*)range
{
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize suggestion;
    do {
        id font = (__bridge_transfer id) CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) fontName, target, NULL);
        NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self attributes:@{(id)kCTFontAttributeName:font}];
        id framesetter = (__bridge_transfer id) CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) string);
        suggestion = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints((__bridge CTFramesetterRef)(framesetter), CFRangeMake(0, self.length), nil, constraint, &fitRange);
    } while (fitRange.length < self.length && target > minimum && (target -= 2.0f));

    if (optimal != NULL) *optimal = target;
    if (range != NULL) *range = NSMakeRange(fitRange.location,fitRange.length);
    return suggestion;
}

@end
```

You use it like so.

```
 CGFloat fontSize = 24.0f;
 NSRange range;
 NSString *title = @"Hello World";
 CGSize suggestedSize = [title sizeWithFontName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" constraints:CGSizeMake(200.0f,35.0f) targetSize:fontSize minimumSize:16.0f optimalFontSize:&fontSize fitRange:&range];
```

*suggestedSize* then contains a CGSize that will fit the title at font *fontSize*. Also *range* tells you how many characters it was able to fit before hitting the minimum size. You can pass NULL to the optimal size and fit range if you don't care.

P.s. I tried re-using the CoreText parts, but it did not work so needs to re-init, but it's still pretty fast, and since you are running on a background thread it will be fine.

P.p.s I wrote a similar method with better performance if you only need to get the height for a single line of text. https://gist.github.com/duedal/4742069

Answer (score 0):

WebCore/WebKit is not fully thread-safe and must run on the main thread. Problem is, font and string manipulation use WebKit under the covers.

Call your string drawing (that includes sizing) code on the main thread and the crashes should stop.

Comment: Hmm.. the issue is that I need the height of this string for further UITableView stuff.. it's not about the drawing

Comment: Getting the height of the string is the same as drawing it as far as UIKit/WebKit are concerned. You'll have to run that one line on the main thread. Something like `__block CGSize size = CGSizeZero; dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { size = [string ...]; });` would probably suffice.

Comment: Briefly for each call to UIKit, yes. But you must run UIKit code on the main thread anyway. It isn't optional.